# Acessing directory in bucket S3 and getting the itens

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, bucket

I am having some issues understanding the documentation, I have something like this in my bucket:

```
—- videos
      —-carvideos
         Tesla.video
         Chevrolet.video
      Car.png
      Bike.png

—-Files
```

And I want to access  the `video` directory and get the `car.png` file, And to enter  the `carvideos` directory and get **all the videos** in it.How do I do that?

My code:

```
import boto3
s3 =boto3.resource(‘s3’, access_key, secret_acess_key)


bucket = s3.Bucket(‘name of my bucket’)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `car.png` file like this:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

s3.Object('mybucket', 'videos/Car.png').download_file('/tmp/Car.png')
```

Note that the filename (Key) of the object includes the **full path** to the object.

To obtain a listing of all objects in the `carvideos` directory, you can use:

```py
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('mybucket')

objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='videos/carvideos/')

for object in objects:
  print(object.Key)
```